# How can I specify alternative above element if the above is missing?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

In a relative layout if I have a series of widgets/views as follows:

```
A  E  
B      
C   
D
```

and B,C,D may or may not be visible at runtime how can I make sure that they are stacked like that?
Because if I set for C bellow B and D bellow C if B is missing and A is missing then C and C and D all stack up to the top right?
Is there a way to specify `layout_bellow=C` and if missing `layout_bellow=B`?
**Note:** I can't use a linear layout. I am using already a linear layout (vertical) but I have another issue with this and I want to convert to relative if possible
**Note:** The views are much more than A,B,C,D and more complicated. So I am looking if this is possible from XML than via code

Comment: I think `LinearLayout` is better for this purpose.. Are you sure you can't use it? Can you explain?

Comment: Are they INVISIBLE or GONE? Invisible Views still fill the space, although they are not shown.

Comment: @Sebastian:Nice one! I wanted to avoid that because I would also need to change many things in the code.

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin:I already use linear layout with vertical orientation. But I have another problem completely different to what I am asking and I think I can solve it if I convert this part of the layout from linear with vertical to relative layout

Comment: @Sebastian:Also my concern is that because this an item of a list, if I have many items I might have penalty by having all items invisible (performance I mean)